# How to use FILTER function to get the previous row data based on certain fixed conditions in google sheet?

Tags: function, google-sheets, time, filter

[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm using the `Filter` function to get the `Category` based on 2 conditions below:

- The `Time` in column A is greater than/equal to `I3`
- The `Number` in column E is smaller than/equal to the `Number` in `I4`

Based on the 2 conditions above, it will return `category I` as the answer. However, I hope to get the Category before `I` which is `Category H`. Is there any ways to modified the `Filter` function so that the answer return will always be the previous category without changing the 2 conditions? First thing came out in my mind is something like `=FILTER(...)-1`, but it doesn't work that way.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(FILTER(B3:B19, E3:E19<=I4, A3:A19>=I3), B:B, 0)-1, 2))
```

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for your solution, in this case there are only one result which is `category I`, when I changed the `Time`  in cell `I3` to `12:35:33 PM`, it will return `Category B` as an answer which is correct. However, when I tried to zoom into the formula for understanding ( cell `I3` = `12:35:33 PM`), I found out that the `MATCH` function actually return me 5 as an answer, may I know why it give me 5 instead of 7? because the `FILTER` function return 7 categories for me which is `C,D,E,F,G,H,I`

Comment: @weizer if MATCH returns 5 it means that MATCH is looking into row 5 from range B1:B. eg match was found in B5 but the output is just 5. then we insert it into ADDRESS so it will be 5-1 as per your request to return the preceding value. and 2nd ADDRESS argument is 2 meaning 2nd column so the ADDRESS returns B4. this then needs to be converted into actual reference so we use INDIRECT

Comment: Really appreciate your explanation! However, when I was testing with the formula, I found out that when I changed the the time in Cell `I3 `to `12:36:20 PM` and changed the number in Cell `I4` to `181.66`, it didn't return `Category G` as the answer, it shows `NA`. I think that is because of `NA` in `FILTER` function. Is there any way to solve this problem in `FILTER` function? This is the condition that I mean, so I hope to include the row before for checking purpose in `FILTER` function. So sorry for not being clear in the question.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) can get any row/column of boolean as conditions. You can simply offset your them to take the conditions of the row at the bottom of them:

```
=FILTER(B3:B18, E4:E19<=I4, A4:A19<=I3)
```

Notice that doing this makes it so the last row can never be selected.

### References

- [FILTER function (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: Hi Marti, thanks for your solution. However, is there any other method to offset instead of reversing and take the last row by changing the condition? As I mentioned above, the condition is fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @weizer I'm confused on what you mean by "the condition is fixed". Isn't this just a formula on your spreadsheet which you can edit? Am I missing something?